# why GPS returning the same Latitude and Longitude when at travel in Android Device?

Tags: android, gps

In my app, getting location in some time interval by using Alarm Manager. Here is the code,

In LocationListenStart.java (It's BroadcastReceiver class):-

```
Intent intentp = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentp, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
criteria = new Criteria(); 
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
if(provider != null)
{
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, pendingIntent);
}
```

In LocationReceiver.java:-

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   String locationKey = "";
   double mlatitude=0.0;
   double mlongitude=0.0;
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
     locationKey = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;
     if (intent.hasExtra(locationKey)) 
     {
        mlatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mlongitude = location.getLongitude();
     }
     if(LocationListenStart.locationManager != null)
     {
        LocationListenStart.locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListenStart.pendingIntent);
     }
   }
}
```

I have tested the app in HTC device, Some times it sending duplicate location when at traveling, 
If i travel for 2 hours it is not getting same lat and long values, when trying to use 5 hours continuous travel at that time duplicate location sending 3 to 5 minutes. some times getting duplicate location when GPS not available. but in Samsung device this problem is not happened, HTC device only getting this problem. How to solve this issue?

Comment: you can also set: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);`

Comment: requestLocationUpdates() method used and tested this is completely not working in HTC Desire U device.

Comment: but What about other devices?

Comment: I have tested in two device Samsung and HTC, In Samsung everything is working fine but HTC getting problem.

Comment: becoz all the Android Phone have different GPS Location Sensors and also all the devices customized their Android system classes as per there requirement e.i.Sony always customized all Android System classes

Comment: it's working in my NEXUS 5, Samsung S3, Micromax A89S, Sony Xperia M and HTC Desire C but not sure about other devices

Comment: I have tested in HTC Desire C in that device worked well.

Comment: as er my opinion you need to implement this requestLocationUpdates().

Comment: If im not mistaken, HTC has a more option to use GPS accurately beside activating your internet/map access enabling. Did you activate GPS location for accuracy in your settings?

Comment: Yes enabled GPS location service in Settings.